# Cython file won't compile

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I have a huge Python code that runs too slowly. I did not want to rewrite my entire code in C, so I did some research and I came across Cython. I was advised to save my Python code as .pyx and create a setup.py file that would "cytonize" my code and then compile it into C.

However I am getting an error when I type `C:/Users/loic/Documents/maido-cython/setup.py build_ext –inplace` :

```
Compiling C:/Users/loic/Documents/maido-cython/maido-cython.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing C:/Users/loic/Documents/maido-cython/maido-cython.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
[unprintable code]
------------------------------------------------------------

Documents\maido-cython\maido-cython.pyx:1:0: 'maido-cython' is not a valid module name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\loic\Documents\maido-cython\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize("C:/Users/loic/Documents/maido-cython/maido-cython.pyx"),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 934, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1056, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: C:/Users/loic/Documents/maido-cython/maido-cython.pyx
```

Here the code (`maido-cython.py`) and the 4 numpy files (`******_maido_856x512.npy`) that I used (don’t worry I uploaded it on my own Google account): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7P95aWmH4DUek9xcEROb0FQR0E

Here is what I wrote in my setup file:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name = "graphique",
      ext_modules = cythonize("C:/Users/loic/Documents/maido-cython/maido-cython.pyx"),
      )
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please ?

**EDIT:**

I took you advices and changed the files. I also changed the link of the upload: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7P95aWmH4DUcFY0X3JycGlacDQ

I have another issue when I type `C:/Users/loic/Documents/maido/setup.py build_ext –inplace` which has to do with the colon character ":"

```
Compiling C:\Users\loic\Documents\maido\maido_cython.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing C:\Users\loic\Documents\maido\maido_cython.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...


def metFeuForet():
    """ propage le feu a toute la foret pour N etape a l'aide de la fonction propageFeu """

    path = "C:\Users\loic\Documents\maido"
             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

Documents\maido\maido_cython.pyx:258:14: Invalid unicode escape '\U'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\loic\Documents\maido\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize("C:\Users\loic\Documents\maido\maido_cython.pyx"),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 934, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1056, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: C:\Users\loic\Documents\maido\maido_cython.pyx
```

I did not find the corresponding unicode character. What should I add ?

Comment: `maido-cython` => `maido_cython`. Filenames must be valid module names.

Comment: Also, don't name the `.pyx` and the `.py` files with the same base name.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question because I have another issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can perfectly execute a `.py*` file with a radix name like `a-b` but you cannot *import* it.

```
import a-b
```

isn't valid because `a-b` isn't a valid python identifier (interpreted as "a minus b"). Same goes with your cythonize process and the `'maido-cython' is not a valid module name` message is clear enough.

Fix: rename `maido-cython.pyx` into a valid python name, `maido_cython.pyx` for instance.

EDIT: for your other issue, it's another classical issue:

```
path = "C:\Users\loic\Documents\maido"
```

`\U` is interpreted as unicode escape. Use raw prefix like this:

```
path = r"C:\Users\loic\Documents\maido"
```

Comment: Can you answer my edited post please ? I have another issue.

Comment: @LoïcPoncin done (it was another unrelated issue). Please don't edit your question further. Think about the future readers of this page.